# RandomCryption.js Decryption

Tags: javascript, encryption

I'm creating a system that creates a completely random cryption system. The only problem I'm having is getting the decryption to work. Please view the snippet below.

```js
RandomCryption = function() {
  var uppercase = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];
  var lowercase = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
  var numbers = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];
  var specChars = [
    "~", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "_", "+", "{",
    "}", "|", ":", '"', "<", ">", "/", "`", "-", "=", "[", "]", "\\", ";",
    '"', ",", ".", "/"
  ];
  
  var RandomValue = function() {
    var randomValue = "";
    var length = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    while (randomValue.length <= length) {
      var charType = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
      var char = null;
      if (charType === 0) {
        char = uppercase[Math.floor(Math.random() * uppercase.length)];
      } else if (charType === 1) {
        char = lowercase[Math.floor(Math.random() * lowercase.length)];
      } else if (charType === 2) {
        char = numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)];
      } else if (charType === 3) {
        char = specChars[Math.floor(Math.random() * specChars.length)];
      }
      randomValue += char;
    }
    return randomValue;
  };
  
  var cryption = {
    A: RandomValue(), a: RandomValue(),
    B: RandomValue(), b: RandomValue(),
    C: RandomValue(), c: RandomValue(),
    D: RandomValue(), d: RandomValue(),
    E: RandomValue(), e: RandomValue(),
    F: RandomValue(), f: RandomValue(),
    G: RandomValue(), g: RandomValue(),
    H: RandomValue(), h: RandomValue(),
    I: RandomValue(), i: RandomValue(),
    J: RandomValue(), j: RandomValue(),
    K: RandomValue(), k: RandomValue(),
    L: RandomValue(), l: RandomValue(),
    M: RandomValue(), m: RandomValue(),
    N: RandomValue(), n: RandomValue(),
    O: RandomValue(), o: RandomValue(),
    P: RandomValue(), p: RandomValue(),
    Q: RandomValue(), q: RandomValue(),
    R: RandomValue(), r: RandomValue(),
    S: RandomValue(), s: RandomValue(),
    T: RandomValue(), t: RandomValue(),
    U: RandomValue(), u: RandomValue(),
    V: RandomValue(), v: RandomValue(),
    W: RandomValue(), w: RandomValue(),
    X: RandomValue(), x: RandomValue(),
    Y: RandomValue(), y: RandomValue(),
    Z: RandomValue(), z: RandomValue(),
    Zero: RandomValue(), One: RandomValue(),
    Two: RandomValue(), Three: RandomValue(),
    Four: RandomValue(), Five: RandomValue(),
    Six: RandomValue(), Seven: RandomValue(),
    Eight: RandomValue(), Nine: RandomValue()
  };
  
  this.Encrypt = function(string) {
    var encryptedString = "";
    for (var c=0; c<string.length; c++) {
      var char = string[c];
      if (cryption[char]) {
        encryptedString += cryption[char];
      } else {
        switch(char) {
          case "0":
            encryptedString += cryption.Zero;
            break;
          case "1":
            encryptedString += cryption.One;
            break;
          case "2":
            encryptedString += cryption.Two;
            break;
          case "3":
            encryptedString += cryption.Three;
            break;
          case "4":
            encryptedString += cryption.Four;
            break;
          case "5":
            encryptedString += cryption.Five;
            break;
          case "6":
            encryptedString += cryption.Six;
            break;
          case "7":
            encryptedString += cryption.Seven;
            break;
          case "8":
            encryptedString += cryption.Eight;
            break;
          case "9":
            encryptedString += cryption.Nine;
            break;
        }
      }
    }
    return encryptedString;
  };
  
  this.Decrypt = function(string) {
    var decryptedString = "";
    var splitString = string.split(" ", string.length);
    var keys = Object.keys(cryption);
    
    for (var w=0; w<splitString.length; w++) {
      var word = splitString[w];
      for (var k=0; k<keys.length; k++) {
        var key = cryption[keys[k]];
        word = word.replace(key, keys[k]);
      }
      console.log(word);
    }
    return decryptedString;
  };
};

var cryption = new RandomCryption();
var decryptedText = document.getElementById("dt");
var encryptedText = document.getElementById("et");

function NewCryption() {
  cryption = new RandomCryption();
  decryptedText.value = "";
  encryptedText.value = "";
}

decryptedText.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  encryptedText.value = cryption.Encrypt(decryptedText.value);
});

encryptedText.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  decryptedText.value = cryption.Decrypt(encryptedText.value);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>RandomCryption.js</title>
    
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <input placeholder="Decrypted Text" id="dt">
    <br/>
    <input placeholder="Encrypted Text" id="et">
    <br/>
    <button onclick="NewCryption()">Create New Cryption</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is the decryption doesn't read properly. Sometimes it works but adds chunks from the cryption variable into the decrypted text. Can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 1):

`this.Decrypt` says: `var splitString = string.split(" ", string.length);`. But I don't see anywhere you added spaces when encrypting the string. So instead of treating each space-separated section separately (corresponding to a single character in the original, unencrypted string), `this.Decrypt` must be only going through the for loop once, with `word = string`. So you need to add spaces when encrypting.

Then you've got `word = word.replace(key, keys[k]);`, which will replace some encrypted parts with the correct characters in spite of the missing spaces problem. However, this is unreliable, as it might replace some characters incorrectly as well. When you find a match, what you want to do is add the decrypted character to `decryptedString`. In other words, replace `word = word.replace(key, keys[k]);` with the following:

```
if (word === key) {
  decryptedString += keys[k];
  break;
}
```

However, your encryption is ambiguous: some characters will be encrypted to the same string. Mostly because (on average) around 20 different characters will be encrypted to the empty string. So you need to change the encryption in some way to prevent duplicate values in `cryption`.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the help.